# Run Macros for MS Access .accdb file with Python

Tags: python, ms-access, macros

I am trying to run a macros query in an .accdb file (the macros executes many queries saving a new table for each query in the DB).

It looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import win32ui
import win32api,time
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
const=win32com.client.constants


  def ejecutarPY():

    src_dir= r"C:\Users\irecasens\Desktop"
    os.chdir(src_dir)

    strDbName = 'test1.accdb'     
    objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")    
    objAccess.Visible = False    
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)     
    objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()      
    objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('GO')     
    objAccess.Application.Quit()     

ejecutarPY()
```

The error it gives is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EjecutarMacros.py", line 25, in <module>
    ejecutarPY()
  File "C:\EjecutarMacros.py", line 20, in ejecutarPY
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
  File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 3, in OpenCurrentDatabase
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurri\xf3 una excepci\xf3n.', (0, None, u'La base de datos ya est\xe1 abierta.', None, -1, -2146820422), None)
```

At the end it says that the DB is already open, but it is not (it is a local file and no one has any access. All the tables inside are also local).

What might be the problem?

Comment: That's nice. Congrats? Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump random code and ... what? admire it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question when providing additional (**important**) information. Don't bury it in the comments.

Comment: For those playing along at home, Google Translate says that "La base de datos ya está abierta." means "The database is now [currently?] open."

Comment: Check your Task Manager for any lingering MSAccess.exe processes. Possibly on an earlier run you did not cleanly exit (usually happens on previous errors).

Answer (score 0):

I started changing some commands to look it like this:

```
def ejecutarPY():

    src_dir= r"C:\Users\..."
    os.chdir(src_dir)
    strDbName = 'C:\Users\....accdb'
    print(strDbName)
    ac = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
    ac.Visible=False

    ac.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
    ac.DoCmd.RunMacro('GO')
    ac.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
    ac = None

ejecutarPY()
```

And it works fine now.

Comment: You should still end the process: `objAccess.Application.Quit()`. Your ending closes the database file but keeps the .exe. open in background.